# Looking for an elegant way of waiting for a payment

Tags: web3js, ether, balances, payments

Is there a better way of awaiting a payment in ETH on a certain eth-address other than looping over `getBalance()`? And how do exchanges manage to find transactions even when they are not confirmed yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to wait for a payment is to wait for a new block and check the transactions included if they send Eth to your account. You need to do this for each new block until you get the amount you're expecting.

To find transactions that haven't been confirmed yet you have to watch the memory pool
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool